# Copy table from .txt file to a new .txt file by skipping certain lines

Tags: powershell, text-files, line, tabular, skip

I have one table (.txt file) in this form:

```
Table:          HHBB
Displayed Fields:  1 of  5    Fixed Columns:         4     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| |ID   |NAME       |Zähler |Obj       |ID-RON      |MANI   |Felder    |Nim      
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| |007  |Kano       |000001 |Lad       |19283712    |       |/HA       |          
| |007  |Bani       |000002 |Bad       |917391823   |       |/LA       |
```

I want to save this table into another .txt file but just want to skip the lines that match `Table` and `Displayed Fields` for example. What I tried:

```
If ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($tempInputRecord2) -or $_ -match "=|Table:|Displayed|----") {
     continue
}
```

How can I do that?

And another question:
What is the best way to write the lines one by one into a new text file?

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to remove the lines which start with `Table:` or `Displayed Fields:` and output results to a new file? Use `Where-Object` to filter lines, and `Out-File` to write them to the file:

```
Get-Content test.txt |
Where-Object { $_ -notlike "Table:*" -and $_ -notlike "Displayed Fields:*" } |
Out-File test2.txt
```

Comment: Niceeee! *.*
Dankeschön, hat super funktioniert!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for simple tasks:

1. If the header to skip occurs only once:

```
Get-Content test.txt|Select-Object -Skip 2|Set-Content test2.txt
```

2. A similar approach to yours with `-notmatch` and RegEx alternation

```
Get-Content test.txt|Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '^Table:|^Displayed Fields:'}|Set-Content test2.txt
```

3. When forcing a complete read in to memory by enclosing in parentheses you can write to the same file:

```
(Get-Content test.txt)|Select-Object -Skip 2|Set-Content test.txt
```